# How to read MySQL time?

Tags: mysql, time

What time is it in MySQL: `1343821692`?

Few aplications that I use store it in that format.

Also I have time stored like this: `2012-08-01 13:41:1` - **how to convert those two time types into each another?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a unix timestamp:

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(1343821692)
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-08-01 13:41:1');
```

See [from_unixtime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) and [unix_timestamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

Comment: Cool! How to convert it back!